# Chrome Blocking Javascript, Google Wave, Google Gadgets

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-wave

**Project:**
Developing a gadget template for Google Wave which will allow my Flash movies to interact with the Wave api. I had to adapt the existing Flex application so that it would work with ActionScript. This was a success.

**Problem:**
Chrome v4.0 is blocking the load and/or execution of javascript files linked to in the Gadget's XML file.

(Already confirmed the gadget works in Chrome v3.0)

**Example & More Details:**
https://wave.google.com/wave/#minimized:nav,minimized:contact,minimized:search,restored:wave:googlewave.com!w%252BLby6vkE9A

**Errors Thrown by Chrome:**

- Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request
- Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

**Resources:**

Search google for wave-as-client

Google Sites site/gumontheshoe/home/my-cabinet

Is there anything I can do from my end to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a different browser. I had the same problem, continued my development in Firefox.

Comment: Considering I want these to be usable by others and Chrome is the flagship of Google, this doesn't seem like a really acceptable answer.

I want everyone to be able to use this regardless of browser.

Comment: i see, i thought your problem was with the GGE tools not working properly in Chrome. I had problems with the GGE in Chrome, while it worked in FF. The published gadget in question however, worked in all browsers once published.

Comment: Nope, its not that the tools aren't working, its just that Chrome appears to be rejecting my Gadget and I'd like to know what I could do to make Chrome accept it. I'm not convinced it is purely a bug as I've seen other Gadgets work now.

Again, my Gadget works in every other Browser and earlier versions of Chrome.